# laravel Auth::attempt passed but redirect to login page because of 'auth' middleware, how to redirect to dashboard?

Tags: laravel, authentication

**my `LoginController\login()` is :**

```
public function login (AdminLoginRequest $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('phone', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.index') ;
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'invalid credentials']);
}
```

**and my route `web.php` is :**

```
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')->prefix('dashboard')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/index', function () {
        echo 'hi there';
    })->name('dashboard.index');
});
```

but the route 'dashboard.inde' never open, unless I remove the `middleware('auth')`.

when I `dd(Auth::user())` after attempt, the user correct values returned.
why I can't call my route?

Answer (score 0):

You have to regenerate your session in order to authenticate successfully. Here you can read more: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users
Try to add this line to your Code:

```
 $request->session()->regenerate();
```

so that your controller method looks like this:

```
public function login (AdminLoginRequest $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('phone', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.index') ;
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'invalid credentials']);
}
```

Comment: I add it, it's not work

Comment: Are you using the default user model to authenticate or any other? Because your $request is type of AdminLoginRequest? Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using laravel 9.5 and yes my model is default user model.